# Constructor en pascal

Tags: poo, pascal, lazarus

Al llamar a "establecerNombre" me sale error y no sé como solocionarlo:

```
constructor create(n:String; ins:cadenas; rit:String; arts:cadenas; min, max:Integer);

    nombre := n;
    establecerInstrumentacion(ins);
    establecerRitmo(rit);
    establecerArtistas(arts);
    establecerBPM(min, max);

end;
```

Comment: ¿Qué error te sale? Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Además puedes leer [mcve]. Con el código proporcionado en tu pregunta, no se puede determinar dónde ocurre el error. Saludos

Comment: ¿Dónde está esa llamada a `establecerNombre`?

Comment: En una clase de Pascal